# Why my Django view return None as HttpResponse?

Tags: python, django

This is a function I used in Django view to accept post request, however it returns None sometimes, any idea about this problem?

```
def acceptpost(request):
    try:
        print "request.method:", request.method
        print "content_type:", request.content_type
        print "request.body:",request.body
        time.sleep(0.1)
    except Exception as e:
        log.error(e)
        return HttpResponse("error")
    return HttpResponse("OK")
```

The function I used to post data is:

```
def post_data(url, data)
    try:
        req = requests.post(url=url, data=data, verify=False)
        response = req.status_code
        content = req.content
    except RequestException as e:
        response = e.response
        log_debug.error("HttpResponse: %s" % response)
        continue
```

This function is in `While True`,
url is: url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/acceptpost/'.

In most of time, I could get the right HttpResponse, which is "ok" in this case, and some time I could only get None, both of the two function runs on localhost, the web server is the Django web server with the address http://127.0.0.1/acceptpost/. 
I have not catch any log in function `acceptpost`, however there are `HttpResponse None` occasionally, is any idea about this problem?

Comment: can you show the full code of your post?? the url the data

Comment: Hi, the question has been modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code in itself doesn't seem to have a problem. The `None` you get comes from `e.response` which here equals `None`. This probably means that your request was not sent, thus there is no response to it.

`RequestException` is a generic exception covering several kind of exceptions. I suggest you see [this manual page](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/_modules/requests/exceptions/)  (not sure if it is up to date but still gives a pretty good insight of the many exceptions you can get). Differentiating most exceptions in your code will help you debug it I think.

Comment: Thank you, it is right, when there is RequestException, e.response is None in my case, more detail information could be get with e.message, another easy way to get more info is using log.error(e) instead of log.error(e.response).